# Is the issue with KBA activation through DOCUSIGN API resolved?

Tags: docusignapi

I am facing issue while trying to enable "ID Check $" through docusign Rest API.

I could see there were lot of work arounds provided. Still following I am not successful.

It would be great if someone can comment if the issue with KBA is still there or any sample code for REST JSON would be greatly appreciated.

Due to this I am thinking of TWO templates one with KBA enabled and other without. So I can take a decision to use the template based on my business rule

Appreciate your time

The following way of creating the envelope did not result in KBA to the signer

```
{
    "accountId": "YYY",
    "templateId":"ZZZ",
    "status": "SENT",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "name": "AAA",
            "roleName": "CCC",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [],
                "checkBoxTabs": [],
                "emailTabs": [],
                "dateTabs": [],
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "BBB",
            "roleName": "DDD",
            "email": "example@example.com",
            "accessCode": "A380",
            "requireIdLookup": "true",
            "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $",           
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [],
                "checkBoxTabs": [],
                "emailTabs": [],
                "dateTabs": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating an Envelope using a DocuSign Template, and want to sometimes require ID Check authentication and other times not, the way you can accomplish this is to use *Composite Templates* in your **Create Envelope** API call.

In your template (i.e., via the DocuSign UI), don't select any form of advanced recipient authentication (i.e., simply set Identify = "Email").

Then, to create an envelope using the template via the API, and specify ID Check as the recipient authentication method, the **Create Envelope** request would look like this:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

{
"emailSubject": "Please sign",
"emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "templateId": "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "sallysemail@test.com",
                            "name": "Sally Adamson",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Signer1",
                            "requireIdLookup": "true",
                            "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The request for creating an envelope (using the same template) that does NOT require any advanced form of recipient authentication would look identical to the request above -- except that it would NOT include the **requireIdLookup** property or the **idCheckConfigurationName** property.

Comment: However i have a curiosity question. Why it did not work if i create an evelope from template in a plain format. Can you please check my updated EDIT?

Comment: Essentially, a "templateRole" object only supports a small number of properties (name, email, roleName, etc.) -- it doesn't support the requireId lookup property or the idCheckConfigurationName property, so DocuSign just ignores those properties in your request. The "recipient" object (i.e., "signer" object) however, DOES support the requireId lookup property and the idCheckConfigurationName property -- therefore you create the envelope using Composite Templates (as shown in my answer), so that you can specify recipient info using the recipient (signer) object (and include ID check props).